# How to create directory in Ubuntu using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, directory, digital-ocean

I want to create a directory for each user when they activated their account in laravel Usercontroler.

but it doesn't work with below code

```
 $path = '/var/www/dngo/files/local/' . $object->id;
 File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

*Apache Document root is `/var/www/dngo/public`

*Ubuntu VPS is18.10 and hosted on digitalocean.

Comment: Have you checked, if the user under which php is running can create folders in /var/www/dngo/public?

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: this will create a directory for your `$object->id` should it doesn't exist yet: `Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('myfolder/'.$object->id,$request->file('file_textbox'), 'filename.txt');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

first of all give permission for example create user folder  in storage directory in laravel then open terminal and give permission like that

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/dngo/storage
```

> if you does not give group permission to project then also run this
>   command

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/dngo
```

now in your userController add this line

```
$storagePath = storage_path('user/'.$object->id);

File::isDirectory($storagePath) or File::makeDirectory($storagePath, 0777, true, true);
```

> first check directory exists then not create other wise create new
>   folder

Comment: Thanks It Works Now